# Ios How to open webview inside app

Tags: ios, webview, calendar

Hello guys i am stuck in problem while using Web View in my application.I want to open ios native calender in my app For this  i am using web view Here is my Code

```
 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com"]]];
[uiviewCalendar addSubview:webView];
```

This work good as expectations but when i pass the url of calendar its goes out of the app and show me calendar.On top it says back to myAppName here is my code

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]]];
[uiviewCalendar addSubview:webView];
```

Is there i am doing something wrong or i cant use native calendar inside my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to integrate an external native app to your own app within UIWebView.

Comment: Thanks for your response can it is possible to add native calendar with out using UIWebView  LIke to add this line of Code : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];